# Facebook FB.login popup opens invalid URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my website i am using FB Javascript SDK for providing my users to login with their FaceBook account instead of filling up register form.

The problem is from today morning, when i click on the "Signin with Facebook" button, it opens popup with the URL

> https://www./login.php?skip_api_login=1

instead of https://www.facebook.com/login.php which is not a valid url.

why the URL is comming like this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue (I would just post a comment but apparently you need 50 rep) so this is not a complete answer. To provide more info it seems it may be a temporary bug, if the user you've been logging in as is currently logged into facebook, the user is logged in straight away. If the user isn't, this loggin error occurs. Obviously once it perceives it that way, you can't go back to a new user because it skips the loggin screen. Perhaps facebook is expecting that user to be logged in which leads to this errornous way of dealing with it.

Comment: yes if the user already logged in FB its working. till yesterday it worked even if user is not already logged in